# How would I append to new line, results on jquery click

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I have a function, which for now just generates a random number on a button click. It currently just overrides the current number generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Number Generator</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<?php 
// $random_number_array = [];
    function generatedNumbers(){
        $random_number_array = range(0, 100);
        shuffle($random_number_array );
        $random_number_array = array_slice($random_number_array ,0,10);

        foreach ($random_number_array as $key => $value) {
           print_r($value);
        }

    }

    if (isset($_GET['run'])) {
    generatedNumbers();
  }
;
 ?>
<body>
    <a href='index.php?run=true'>Generate</a>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to generated on a new line the numbers as an array, so per click generate new line with a new set of numbers

Comment: Store the numbers in a session / GET array and you can use `random_int / rand` to generate random numbers.

Comment: You'll have to use jquery ajax to call your number function on click and use jquery append to add it to the dom. You need to update your question with the javascript you've tried if you need help with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution 1:***

If you want to achieve your desired result by using only `PHP` then you can follow this example:

**HTML:**

```
<a href='index.php?run=true'>Generate</a>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
session_start(); // need to use session_start to store array in session.

function generatedNumbers(){
    $random_number_array = range(0, 100);
    shuffle($random_number_array);
    $random_number_array = array_slice($random_number_array,0,10);
    foreach ($random_number_array as $key => $value) {
       $myArray[] = $value; // store values in array
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['data']) && count($_SESSION['data']) > 0){
        $myArray = array_merge($_SESSION['data'],$myArray); // merge new and old array if exist in session.
    }

    $_SESSION['data'] = $myArray;    // reset the value in session.
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($myArray);
}

if (isset($_GET['run'])) {
   generatedNumbers();
}
?>
```

**Some Explanation:**

In `PHP` you can get the desired output by using `session`, you can store all values into an array then you can use `$_SESSION` for next result, in last you can merge old and new data together by using `array_merge()`

---

***Solution 2:***

You can also get the desired result by using jQuery / Ajax:

**Front End:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='javascript:void(0);' id="generate">Generate</a>

<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#generate").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "index2.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "run=1",
                dataType: "html",  // Has to be false to be able to return response
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#result").html(response);
                }
            });  // JQUERY Native Ajax End
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, you need to call `index2.php` by using ajax, your `index2.php` having following code:

**index2.php:**

```
<?php 
session_start(); // need to use session_start to store array in session.
function generatedNumbers(){
    $random_number_array = range(0, 100);
    shuffle($random_number_array);
    $random_number_array = array_slice($random_number_array,0,10);
    foreach ($random_number_array as $key => $value) {
       $myArray[] = $value; // store values in array
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['data']) && count($_SESSION['data']) > 0){
        $myArray = array_merge($_SESSION['data'],$myArray); // merge new and old array if exist in session.
    }

    $_SESSION['data'] = $myArray;    // reset the value in session.
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION['data']);
}

if (isset($_GET['run'])) {
   generatedNumbers();
}
?>
```

**Side note:** index.php and index2.php must be in same directory.